# Was an uppercase j used to replace an uppercase i letter on German monument inscriptions?

Tags: writing, german

I have seen it on two grave inscriptions ([photo](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/blog.nus.edu.sg/dist/7/4236/files/2017/04/Carl_Schilling_Grab-26t7mno.jpg)). Both were of on a grave of a person called Ida but there was Jda on the grave inscription. They lived in the 19th and 20th centuries in Central Europe, Germany.

Is this a linguistic phenomenon? Like writing V instead of U in Latin language historical inscriptions?

Using V instead of U makes some sense to me. The original Latin alphabet written with modern equivalent letters is:

A B C D E F Z H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X

where is no U, so it is logical to use V as U. This reasoning fails to explain why there could be I replaced by J, if in the alphabet above, there is I but not J...

EDIT: J in German can have several pronunciations: jemand, Jll (river name, sounds like "ill"),

Comment: There was no consonant 'v' in Latin. The letter 'u' was represented with straight sides in inscriptions because it was easier to carve. Are your grave inscriptions in the old German lettering?

Comment: The canonicall name seems to be "Ill", and it is only sometimes written as "Jll" to avoid confusion between the letters, according to wp: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ill_(Elsass)

Comment: @KateBunting there definitely was a consonant 'V' in Latin. A consonant is defined by speech, and what we transcribe as 'V' and 'U' nowadays were distinct sounds with the former functioning as a consonant and the latter a vowel. Both sounds were represented as 'V' in Classical Latin, but that doesn't mean the distinction between vowel and consonant didn't exist.

Comment: @PCLuddite - I was referring to Classical Latin - see [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/28/non-typographical-evidence-of-v-being-pronounced-as-w#)

Comment: @KateBunting I was too. The consonant V existed in Classical Latin. It was not pronounced as the same as a vowel V. The linked question supports my previous comment

Comment: @PCLuddite You you provide a source to support this statement?

Comment: @Riwen see the answer to the [question linked by Kate Bunting](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/28/non-typographical-evidence-of-v-being-pronounced-as-w)..... making reference to a consonantal V. Pronounced differently (but having evolved from) the vowel V. This is not a controversial statement but seems to be a common misconception based on the idea that a letter can only ever be either a vowel or consonant.

Comment: @PCLuddite What I mean is, did Classical Latin have the *sound* /v/ (voiced labiodental fricative)? If so, do you have any source to support it? I'm not talking about letters, but phonology.

Comment: @Riwen no, it did not. I never claimed it did. I only claimed that V represented a consonant in Classical Latin. It was pronounced as /w/, but that is still a consonant, used to separate syllables, and distinct from the vowel pronunciation /u/ and /u:/.

Comment: @Riwen you may not have been talking about letters, but I was talking about both phonology and the representation (letters). V represented the consonant /w/ as well as the vowel /u:/

Comment: @PCLuddite Okay, it's much clearer now, thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Fraktur, a typeface that was common in Germany until well into the 20th century, uses a capital I that is very much alike to a capital J in other fonts. See [these samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur#Typeface_samples) on Wikipedia; the capital J has an extra dash:

[image]

As others pointed out in the comments, this is actually common to other writing scripts, also because a capital I can be very similar to a lower case l.

Comment: I actually think cursive writing even today uses an I that looks very much like a printed J, just shorter. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinfachte_Ausgangsschrift

Comment: The grave inscription is not in Fraktur. Here is a [photo](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/blog.nus.edu.sg/dist/7/4236/files/2017/04/Carl_Schilling_Grab-26t7mno.jpg) of the grave.

Comment: @Janik: Please add that link to the question post. Comments are ephemeral, subject to deletion at any time.

Comment: There is even a capital I at the bottom for `Dipl Ing`

Comment: @Janik then probably the person making the grave inscription misread the original writing (somewhere) written in Fraktur?

Comment: @Zibelas but that's on a later addition - I wouldn't want to assume a stonemason half a century later would match the letter forms or even know how to, especially as they already used a different stroke weight

Answer (score 23):

> Can uppercase j be used to replace an uppercase i letter on a German monument inscription?

Before 1945, it was common place to replace uppercase 'i' with an uppercase 'j' letter.

The main reason was that in the past a uppercase 'I' was written (in the Antiqua type set) as a vertical line (without the now common horizontal bars on the top and bottom) and thus looked the same as a lowercase 'l' that was also written as a vertical line.

Uppercase 'J' was therefore used to make the distinction clear.

> [J - Verwendung in der deutschen Sprache – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/J#Verwendung_in_der_deutschen_Sprache):
>
> - Jll, Jller, Jlmenau, Jllustrierte
> - Ill, Iller, Ilmenau, Illustrierte
>
> > [image]

---

If you look at the bottom of the sample image, you will see 'Dipl. Ing.' (where 'J' is not used and is  dated with 1978).

It looks the same as the 'l' of 'Dipl'.

[image]

---

Even when Fraktur was used, the uppercase letter 'J' was often used instead of an uppercase 'I'.

[Berliner Illustrierte Zeitung Archiv 1895 - 1945 | Historische-Magazine.de](https://www.historische-magazine.de/berliner-illustrierte-zeitung/)

| 1895-09-22 | 1912-04-28 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

[Berliner Illustrirte Zeitung - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berliner_Illustrirte_Zeitung)

> Also in 1941, the old-fashioned spelling of its name (sometimes described as a mistake), which had been retained when the masthead was modernised at the turn of the century,
> was finally changed to the more modern *Illustri**e**rte* [from *Illustrirte*].

- the usage of the uppercase letter 'J' was not changed

Comment: The way I learnt writing in elementary school I and J still looked almost interchangeable. The curve for the J was lower but apart from that tey looked the same

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is much simpler: the name Ida is sometimes written Jda; the inscription says Jda because the woman wrote her name that way.

This does not mean that *in general* one can substitute the letter J for the letter I in German. It is a peculiarity of the name Ida.

- A semi-well-known example is the *[Prospect vom Berge Jda](https://www.antikvariatbretschneider.cz/shop/amerika/11015-mount-ida-meyer-oceloryt-1860.html)* (A view from mount Ida), engraved by Albert Henry Payne after a painting by William Henry Bartlett, c. 1850). (The Mount Ida in question is neither of the two classical Mount Idas, but rather some hill in New York State, U.S.A.)
- [Here is an article](https://www.entlebucher-anzeiger.ch/2014/06/ski-weltmeisterin-jda-sch%C3%B6pfer-verstorben.html) from the newspaper *Entlebucher Anzeiger*, dated 20 June 2014: "Ski-Weltmeisterin Jda Schöpfer verstorben", ski woman-world-champion [Ida Schoepfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ida_Sch%C3%B6pfer) is dead. (Note that the article has both Jda and Ida. Newspapers these days.)

German Wikipedia [has this to say](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=J&oldid=231385728):

> Bis heute gibt es noch ältere Schreiber, die anstelle des Großbuchstabens I ein J verwenden (z. B. Jda, Jtalien). Auch bei serifenlosen Schriften wird manchmal ein großes J anstelle eines großen I gesetzt. Ein Grund dafür ist, dass bei derartigen Schriften das große I und das kleine L oft schwer oder gar nicht unterscheidbar sind, vor allem wenn beide Buchstaben nebeneinanderstehen (etwa in Jll, Jller, Jlmenau, Jllustrierte im Unterschied zu Ill, Iller, Ilmenau, Illustrierte).

> Bei einigen Fremdwörtern existiert sowohl eine nach der neuen deutschen Rechtschreibung gültige eingedeutschte Schreibweise mit J, als auch eine fachsprachliche mit I (z. B. Iod, neben Jod). In der Chemie wird die Schreibweise mit I sogar bevorzugt.

Translation:

> To this day there are older writers who use a J instead of the capital I (e.g. Jda, Jtalien). A capital J is sometimes used instead of a capital I in sans serif fonts. One reason for this is that in such typefaces, the uppercase I and the lowercase L are often difficult or impossible to distinguish, especially when both letters are next to each other (e.g. in Jll, Jller, Jlmenau, Illustrierte as opposed to Ill, Iller, Ilmenau, Illustrierte).

> For some foreign words, there is both a German spelling with J, which is valid according to the new German orthography, and a technical spelling with I (e.g. Iod, next to Jod). In chemistry, the spelling with I is even preferred.

Answer (score 5):

The convention of replacing uppercase I with J seems to be used in other languages, too. I recently visited a WW1 war grave with a monument commemorating Italian POWs:

> Agli Eroi d‘Jtalia
>
> 1914-1918

[Italian does not use the letter J in native words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography#Alphabet), so replacing I with J shouldn't be problematic regarding pronunciation.